# Clone a GET request-based website

Tags: wget, clone, mirroring, httrack

I'm trying to make a static clone of a website because it's running on some ancient CMS that's going to crash any minute now.

I've tried using `httrack` and `wget`, but none of them work.

The problem is, that the site uses a link system similar to what WordPress uses by default: a single file, using GET requests to serve appropriate content (`example.com/index.php?name=News`).

HTTrack just assumes it's all the same file and stops immediately. Wget does download everything, but it doesn't replace the links (also it's impossible to serve files with question marks in them).

Is there a tool that supports this kind of link schema?

Comment: What should wget replace the link to?

Comment: @GombaiSándor from what I understand it should replace all links with relative ones so that the links go to the mirrored files, not the live site.

Comment: wget can serve you with several nice features when it downloads static data but what you are getting now is generated by some engine. It's not a tree that it has to walk which it could translate into another tree for you.

Comment: You need FTP access to get at the actual logic rather then viewing the generated output.

Comment: @Burgi I have full access to the source, but the site is very unstable, that's why I want to make a static copy. I think I found a solution tho. I'll leave an answer if I get it working.